# How Apache handles .htaccess file changes? Are they reparsed on each request?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, apache2.2, apache2.4

I'm wondering, how .htaccess files are implemented in Apache? Are they really reparsed in each subsequent request or cached somewhere and reparsed only when changed?

How change tracking of these files is implemented? stat() for filechanges on each request or via inotify()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` files should not be used unless you don't have access to the apache config. e.g. shared hosting. Since VPS/Cloud servers are abundant these days at very low costs, there is almost no reason to get shared hosting.

`.htaccess` files are actually read on every request because it uses per directory context. So using them causes a slight performance hit. Even just having `AllowOverride All` in your config has the same effect even if you don't use the `.htaccess` file.

The misconception that .htaccess files are needed is because most software e.g. `wordpress` or other cmses tell you to add your code there. That was because most hosting was shared in years past and people didn't have access to the Apache config file unless you bought expensive VPS' or dedicated servers.

I don't believe there is any tracking at all and probably isn't needed because it reads the `.htaccess` file on every request regardless if a change was made or not. So that's why they are completely inefficient and shouldn't be used. Put your rules and directives in your virtual host file and you'll have a better server.

You can read [When not to use .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) from Apache.